# Message: Undefined index: REMOTE_HOST in $_SERVER

Tags: php

Why do I get this error when I try to retrieve host name of remote user ?

```
Message: Undefined index: REMOTE_HOST
```

When reading documentation I came to know that it needs to be enabled in httpd.conf. But I am not sure what needs to be edited in httpd.conf.

Comment: question belongs on serverfault? (though there are php-side workarounds)

Comment: Are you invoking PHP on the command line? `REMOTE_HOST` will not be set.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is not an error, it's a notice. REMOTE_HOST is not defined in all cases. REMOTE_ADDR is. You need to reconfigure your webserver if you need it. `HostnameLookups On` does it, but it incurs a slowdown.

Alternative: Let PHP do the lookup, so you can skip it (for speed) when not needed:

```
$r = $_SERVER["REMOTE_HOST"] ?: gethostbyaddr($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
```

Comment: This will cause NOTICE message if $_SERVER["REMOTE_HOST"] is undefined. In testing environment it is advisable to get rid of notices as well because they can easily become errors later under some circumstances. `$r = array_key_exists( 'REMOTE_HOST', $_SERVER) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] : gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);` is better in that respect. And don't use double quotes unless you have to, single quotes execute faster.

Comment: One can use the null coalesce `??` if CLI support is a concern. And no, single quotes being "faster" is a dated misconception: https://nikic.github.io/2012/01/09/Disproving-the-Single-Quotes-Performance-Myth.html

Comment: Read comments there are at least 2 examples there which point that single quotes is still faster - http://www.phpbench.com/

Comment: @Coder12345 I don't bother with micro-optimizations. Anyone who ever used a profiler wouldn't.

Comment: if this is slow, store the result of `$_SESSION['REMOTE_HOST']=gethostbyaddr($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"])` and then use the $_SESSION instead

Answer (score 6):

The [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) for `REMOTE_HOST` in `$_SERVER` says:

> Your web server must be configured to
>   create this variable. For example in
>   Apache you'll need HostnameLookups On 
>   inside httpd.conf for it to exist.

Answer (score 6):

```
$r = $_SERVER["REMOTE_HOST"] ?: gethostbyaddr( $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]); // Will still cause the error/notice message
```

In order to avoid the message one should use:

```
$r = array_key_exists( 'REMOTE_HOST', $_SERVER) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] : gethostbyaddr( $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
```

Or the simpler:

```
$r = is_set( $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] : gethostbyaddr( $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
```

Or as from PHP 7 the simplest:

```
$r = $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] ?? gethostbyaddr( $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
```

And this is why I love PHP !

Answer (score 2):

I have faced this problem when using PHPUnit. This is how I deal with:

```
  $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]     = array_key_exists( 'REMOTE_ADDR',      $_SERVER) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']     : '127.0.0.1'; 
  $_SERVER["REMOTE_HOST"]     = array_key_exists( 'REMOTE_HOST',      $_SERVER) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']     : gethostbyaddr($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
  $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] = array_key_exists( 'SERVER_PROTOCOL',  $_SERVER) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] : "HTTP/1.1";
  $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]  = array_key_exists( 'REQUEST_METHOD',   $_SERVER) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']  : "GET";
  $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]     = array_key_exists( 'SERVER_PORT',      $_SERVER) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']     : "80";
  $_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"] = array_key_exists( 'SERVER_SOFTWARE',  $_SERVER) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] : "Apache";
  $_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT"]     = array_key_exists( 'HTTP_ACCEPT',      $_SERVER) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']     : "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,application/json";
  $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]       = array_key_exists( 'HTTP_HOST',        $_SERVER) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']       : "www.site.com";
  $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] = array_key_exists( 'HTTP_USER_AGENT',  $_SERVER) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36';
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit httpd.conf in your web server, add this line ***HostnameLookups On*** at the end of the file, save and restart your server.