# Pound & Apache: REMOTE_HOST contains host of proxy

Tags: apache, localhost, reverse-proxy

I have a server running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, Pound 2.6 and Apache 2.2. I have also the apache module mod_rpaf (installed from https://github.com/gnif/mod_rpaf) installed and enabled to ensure, that in the variable REMOTE_ADDR appears the real user ip address and not the address of the proxy.
This works fine, but the variable REMOTE_HOST is not changed by mod_rpaf. This variable contains "localhost" and not the host of the given user ip address.

Can you help me, please?

Here is my mod_rpaf configuration:

```
root@perseus ~ # cat /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rpaf.conf 
RPAF_Enable       On
RPAF_ProxyIPs     127.0.0.1
RPAF_Header       X-Forwarded-For
RPAF_SetHostName  On
RPAF_SetHTTPS     On
RPAF_SetPort      On
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [theses answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178827/message-undefined-index-remote-host-in-server) on a previous question about a missing REMOTE_HOST:

REMOTE_HOSTS is a variable that may or may not be populated by apache (and it's better if it is not set, else it imply a DNS query by apache for every incoming request). So Nothing on your code should rely on REMOTE_HOST. No application should assume this variable will be there and correctly filled.

mod_rpaf does what it is designed for, documentation:

> Sets REMOTE_ADDR, HTTPS, and HTTP_PORT to the values provided by an upstream proxy.

Now you have a working REMOTE_ADDR, which is the only variable you should trust, make a copy of it in REMOTE_HOST if you really wants that, and simply do it in your application code.

Comment: `HostnameLookups` is already set to `Off`

Comment: yes, so why do you want something in REMOTE_HOST?

Comment: What I dislike is only the incorrect value. I don't know if this variable is used by programs on my server. I would prefer that this variable isn't set instead of having this incorrect value.

Comment: try with `UnsetEnv REMOTE_HOST` then.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in Ubuntu LTS 12.04 that prevents rpaf to work at all.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libapache2-mod-rpaf/+bug/1002571

workaround

in rpaf.conf replace

```
<IfModule mod_rpaf.c>
```

by

```
<IfModule mod_rpaf-2.0.c>
```